# put two columns from two different datasets together into one column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes

df1

| name |
| --- |
| Elias |
| David |
| Simon |
| Manuel |

and a second df2

| name |
| --- |
| Gabriel |
| Brian |
| Simona |
| Danielle |
| Dilara |
| Martin |
| David |
| Simon |

I one to put them into one column

I expecting an output like these:

| name |
| --- |
| Elias |
| David |
| Simon |
| Manuel |
| Gabriel |
| Brian |
| Simona |
| Danielle |
| Dilara |
| Martin |

where every name occur once, so remove also duplicates.

i tried these

```
frames = [df1,df2]
```

but these gave me something different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the columns names are 'A' and 'B':

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1['A'], df2['B']], axis = 0).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

**here we are creating two data frame by using pd.Series **

```py
df1 = pd.Series(['a', 'b'])
df2 = pd.Series(['c', 'd'])
```

**and using pd.concat we concatenate df1 dataframe firstly with df2 dataframe**

```py
pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

**as you can see the output df1 show firstly and lastely the df2  :**

```
0    a
1    b
0    c
1    d
```

**note:**

*you can concatenate multiple dataframe [df1, df2,....,dfn]*

Comment: While this might answer the question, if possible you should [edit] your answer to include details on *how* this code block answers the question. This helps to provide context and makes your answer much more useful to future readers.

Comment: @Hoppeduppeanut do you know how to make virus ,if you know i will learn from you?